# Build multi-module project with two or more roots in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, multi-module

I just swapped from maven to gradle, because I thought it was a good idea since I could not solve my problem with maven. Well, gradle didnt solve my problem either (thats why you are here, lol) but it is faster and I will continue using it.

Here is what I've got:

```
project/
├── components/
│   ├── Software Component A
│   └── Software Component B
└── modules/
    ├── Module A
    ├── Module B
    ├── Module C
    └── Module D
```

The software components include the modules that are universal for the whole project. I want to be able to run the software with IntelliJ for testing reasons and I want to build two seperate jars for the software components.

And this is how far I came with a smaller set of projects to test renamed to their role:

this is the gradle configuration for the root project:

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '4.1.1'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.freefair.lombok'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    group = 'io.cloudsystem'
    version = '2.0.0'
    compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    javadoc.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2'
        testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

// settings.gradle
rootProject.name = 'gradle_root_project'
include 'module_a', 'module_b', 'module_c', 'software_component_a'
```

and this for the software component (settings always only: `rootProject.name = 'projectname'`)

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'io.cloudsystem.Controller'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':ModuleLoader')
    implementation project(':TerminalModule')
    implementation project(':NetworkModule')
}
```

This whole thing builds now with `gradle build` but all I get is a set of useless jars... the component does not run, the root file is only an empty manifest and when I run the project in IntelliJ (works only when I opened the root project, otherwise there are missing imports) the output is weird/ displayed wrong or not even displayed.

Comment: Are you attempting to create a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)?

Comment: I don't think so as he is including the modules like in a normal multi-project structure. But I have another question: when you say your components don't run, how are you running them?

Comment: @Slaw that sounds pretty much like the thing I need.. I will try to solve it with your suggestion

Comment: @BjørnVester well, I only want to run the component. The modules are just libary like thingies

Comment: That actually solved my problem! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Slaw! The structure I was using is possible using an [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). Anyway [gradle shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) was also required to build a working jar with dependencies. To build it I had to configure it as descriped on their webpage and run `gradle clean shadowJar`.

Comment: Just in case there's any confusion, there is a difference between a _composite build_ and a _multi-project build_. The latter has one or more _sub-projects_ but is still considered a single build; this is similar to a multi-module Maven setup. Whereas the former is a grouping of two or more _builds_; I don't know the equivalent mechanism in Maven, if there is one.